# Node.js app 404 errors for public directory in Google App Engine Flexible production environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, http-status-code-404, static-files

I've been working with the Node.js Google App Engine for some months and have always successfully used the express.static solution to access static files in the public folder when i deployed my node.js app.

For some (to me not so obvious) reason I struggle to get this working lately in the Google Flexible production environment. On my local development environment everything is fine.

In order to narrow down the problem I created a very basic test app listed here:

```
    'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const app     = express()
const path    = require('path')
const os      = require('os')
const PORT    = process.env.PORT || 8080
const ENV     = process.env.NODE_ENV

//app.use(express.static('public'))
//app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`SYSTEM: App listening on port ${PORT}`)
 console.log(`SYSTEM: Press Ctrl+C to quit.`)
})

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
 res.status(200).send('\
  <h1>TEST app.use(express.static("public")) in Google Cloud Flexibel App     Engine environment </h1>\
  <hr/>\
  <h4>YAML settings: runtime: nodejs env: flex</h4>\
  <h4>HOST         : '+`${os.hostname()}`+'</h4>\
  <h4>PORT         : '+`${PORT}`+'</h4>\
  <h4>__dirname    : '+`${__dirname}`+'</h4>\
  <h4>mountpath    : '+`${app.mountpath}`+'</h4>\
  <h4>env          : '+`${ENV}`+'</h4>\
  <h4>path resolved: '+`${path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')}`+'</h4>\
  <h4>path joined  : '+`${path.join(__dirname, 'public')}`+'</h4>\
  <hr/>\
  <h2>If you see me <img src="./HB.png"> you can access "./HB.png" in the "public" directory.</h2>\
  <h2>If you see me <img src="/HB.png">  you can access "/HB.png"  in the "public" directory.</h2>\
  <h2>If you see me <img src="HB.png">   you can access "HB.png"   in the "public" directory.</h2>\
  <hr/>\
 ')
})
```

I tried various settings of the express.static settings (see those commented out). However each time after deploying using
gcloud app deploy
to Google production I get 404 (also in the google logs). On local development environment everything is fine.

Does anyone have a clue ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I solved it by reinstalling the Google Cloud SDK.